# Android WebView does not render before I lock/unlock the screen

Tags: android

So I have an activity with a WebView with the visibility set to Gone on startup. After a button click, I load the web view with content, set it to Visible and call `invalidate()` in that order. Yet, it does not render or layout before I turn off the screen (lock the phone) and then back on again. Why not?

It has set height to `wrap_content`. I'm running Android 4.1 on a HTC one.

Comment: have you solved? I have exactly the same problem on the same phone

Comment: I'm afraid not (or I can't remember, long time ago)